# How to determine Moodle Cache Size?

Tags: php, caching, size, moodle

My Moodle instance starts behaving weirdly when the Cache is full, for example,it doesn't show the hyperlinks. I have to manually "Purge all caches" in Moodle.

I am thinking of writing a script which will do that for me when the cache is full. Is there a way i can find the max cache size in Moodle and compare it with the current size?

Thanks.